# Flutter 2D game graphics

Tags: arrays, flutter, graphics

I was wondering if there is a easy and efficient way to draw an 2D-array to the screen in flutter.

I basically want to display a 2D-graph based on mathematics, I should be able to calculate this function in the Dart language. I also want to do this efficiently since this graph needs to update quite frequently, maybe 20-40 fps or so.

Is this possible in the current state of Flutter? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) package. If you'd like to use a bar graph there's a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ct4Z8qpD5vY). If you'd prefer a line graph here is an [example](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/line_charts/simple.html). Use these in a Stateful widget, and with a little work, I think you'll have what you want.

These aren't the best examples, but there is a lot of documentation and usage of charts_flutter online, and I'm certain you can find what you're looking for with a google search.

I hope this helped.